# Convert object data type column to integer error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have a df with a column that I want to filter for only negative or only positve values,

when I try code below as:

```
df.loc[df['values'] > 0]
```

I get error of

```
`TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I try to convert the object data type of the values column to integer:

```
df['values'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

I get error of : `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.69'`

Thanks!

How Can I convert correctly so I can then filter correctly? Thanks!

Comment: convert it to float (3.69 is a float)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert it to a `float` dtype since 3.69 is a decimal (and therefore a `float`). `int` datatypes can only non-decimal numbers (e.g. 1, 2, 4, 100, 900). Try this:

```
df.loc[df['values'].astype(float) > 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert it to int you should use apply function:

```
df = df.assign(values = lambda x: x['values'].apply(lambda s: int(s)))
```